# Change the Promoted Links Size in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013

I've seen a few answers for this question, however everyone seems to want to make the tiles smaller. I'd like to increase the size of the tiles.

I've found this code, however the issue I am having with it is that the images aren't displaying correctly and seem to be moved to the top left hand corner of the tile only.

The scroll bar is also missing.

Can anyone modify this code to have the images display correctly as well as bring the scroll bar back?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/JQuery/jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    // ImageSize is the size you desire for the tile, the default size is 180
    var ImageSize = "280";
    // promotedlinksbody_WPQ is the id of Promoted link which you could get using inspector.
    var promotedlinksbody_WPQ = "2";
    var numberOfPromotedLinks = $('#promotedlinksbody_WPQ' + promotedlinksbody_WPQ + ' > .ms-tileview-tile-root').length;
    var ControlID='promotedlinksbody_WPQ';
    ControlID=ControlID + promotedlinksbody_WPQ;
    $("#" + ControlID).height(ImageSize);
    for (i = 1; i <= numberOfPromotedLinks; i++) {
        ControlID='Tile_WPQ' + promotedlinksbody_WPQ + '_' + i ;
        ControlID= ControlID + '_1';
        $("#" + ControlID).width(ImageSize);
        $("#" + ControlID).height(ImageSize);
        ControlID='Tile_WPQ' + promotedlinksbody_WPQ + '_' + i ;
        ControlID= ControlID + '_2';
        // when you write ”width(ImageSize-1)“  , a space sized 1px appears between tiles, otherwise they would be stick together like a ribbon.
        $("#" + ControlID).width(ImageSize-1);
        $("#" + ControlID).height(ImageSize);
        ControlID='Tile_WPQ' + promotedlinksbody_WPQ + '_' + i ;
        ControlID= ControlID + '_7';
        $("#" + ControlID).width(ImageSize);
        ControlID='Tile_WPQ' + promotedlinksbody_WPQ + '_' + i ;
        ControlID= ControlID + '_4';
        $("#" + ControlID).width(ImageSize);
        $("#" + ControlID).height(ImageSize);
        $("#" + ControlID).addClass('ms-tileview-tile-detailsBox2');
    }
    ControlID="promotedlinksheader_WPQ" + promotedlinksbody_WPQ;
    $("#" + ControlID).hide();
});
</script>
```